# how to write dataframe data likes '0012' to csv by to_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, dataformat

the code is as following:

```
a={'code':['0012'],'name':['jason']}
DataFrame(a).to_csv('test.csv')
```

it appears that the data '0012' changes to '12' in the test.csv file.
How can I solve the problem? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please provide code of what you have currently, if you want help with your problem...

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':['0012'],'name':['Jason'],'value':[100]},index=[0])

df.to_csv('test.csv')

!type test.csv  #I used type because I am on a windows box, you can use !cat if on linux box
```

Output:

```
,code,name,value
0,0012,Jason,100
```

It does out put 0012, but if you open this in Excel, excel will want to convert 0012 into 12.  You could use quoting to explicitly define as string.

```
df.to_csv('test.csv',quoting=1)
```

Output:

```
"","code","name","value"
"0","0012","Jason","100"
```

Comment: @UncleLAU if this answer helped you, would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. Is there a converting method to let 0012 display in Excel. Because when I use read_csv to read test.csv, it outputs 12 instead of 0012.

Comment: pd.read_csv('test.csv',dtype={'code':'str'})  Use dtype, with a dictionary of column and dtype.

Comment: @UncleLAU You are welcome, and thank you.  Happy coding